# how to open a url from python and let the rest of the program run?

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

I am making a project in which I need to open a url from python.
For this i am using the webbroweser module in python 3.

i am using this command for that -  webbrowser.open("www.google.com")

This is working fine , it opens the browser and takes me to google.com
But the problem is that the rest of the program does not run until i close this window.
This means the python program stops at the function call and waits for me to close this window so that it can continue working .
I dont want this. I want that the program should just open the window and continue working . I should  be able to close this browser window whenever i want and the program should be running parallelly.

It turns out that if i have google chrome already opened and then use webbrowser.open() then the program creates a new tab and continues to run.

But if no tabs of google chrome is opened (i.e the application is not running) then if a use webbrowser.open()  then it opens the application and keeps on waiting ?  I dont want it wait but to keep running

```
import webbrowser
chrome_path= "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s"
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open("www.google.com")
print("end program")
```

Here you can check that if google chrome is already running and you run this program then print statement is executed but if google chorme is not running and you run this program then print statement is executed only after you close the google chrome window

Comment: please, post [mre]. calling `webbrowser.open("www.google.com")` will not block the execution

Comment: post your code. Opening browser window will not stop your program from running